# Parsing an indentation based language using scala parser combinators

Tags: parsing, scala, indentation, parser-combinators

Is there a convenient way to use Scala's parser combinators to parse languages where indentation is significant? (e.g. Python)

Comment: Use `override val skipWhitespace = false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume we have a very simple language where this is a valid program

```
block
  inside
  the
  block
```

and we want to parse this into a `List[String]` with each line inside the block as one `String`.

We first define a method that takes a minimum indentation level and returns a parser for a line with that indentation level.

```
def line(minIndent:Int):Parser[String] = 
  repN(minIndent + 1,"\\s".r) ~ ".*".r ^^ {case s ~ r => s.mkString + r}
```

Then we define a block with a minimum indentation level by repeating the line parser with a suitable separator between lines.

```
def lines(minIndent:Int):Parser[List[String]] =
  rep1sep(line(minIndent), "[\n\r]|(\n\r)".r)
```

Now we can define a parser for our little language like this:

```
val block:Parser[List[String]] =
  (("\\s*".r <~ "block\\n".r) ^^ { _.size }) >> lines
```

It first determines the current indentation level and then passes that as the minimum to the lines parser. Let's test it:

```
val s =
"""block
    inside
    the
    block
outside
the
block"""

println(block(new CharSequenceReader(s)))
```

And we get

```
[4.10] parsed: List(    inside,     the,     block)
```

For all of this to compile, you need these imports

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader
```

And you need to put everything into an object that extends `RegexParsers` like so

```
object MyParsers extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, no, the Scala parser combinators don't have support for this kind of thing out of the box. You can certainly do it by parsing white space in a meaningful way, but you will encounter some problems since you need some form of state machine to keep track of the indentation stack.

I would recommend doing a preprocessing step. Here is a little preprocessor which adds markers to separate indented blocks:

```
object Preprocessor {

    val BlockStartToken = "{"
    val BlockEndToken = "}"

    val TabSize = 4 //how many spaces does a tab take

    def preProcess(text: String): String = {
        val lines = text.split('\n').toList.filterNot(_.forall(isWhiteChar))
        val processedLines = BlockStartToken :: insertTokens(lines, List(0))
        processedLines.mkString("\n")
    }

    def insertTokens(lines: List[String], stack: List[Int]): List[String] = lines match {
        case List() => List.fill(stack.length) { BlockEndToken } //closing all opened blocks
        case line :: rest => {
            (computeIndentation(line), stack) match {
                case (indentation, top :: stackRest) if indentation > top => {
                    BlockStartToken :: line :: insertTokens(rest,  indentation :: stack)
                }
                case (indentation, top :: stackRest) if indentation == top =>
                    line :: insertTokens(rest, stack)
                case (indentation, top :: stackRest) if indentation < top => {
                    BlockEndToken :: insertTokens(lines, stackRest)
                }
                case _ => throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid algorithm")
            }
        }
    }


    private def computeIndentation(line: String): Int = {
        val whiteSpace = line takeWhile isWhiteChar
        (whiteSpace map {
            case ' ' => 1
            case '\t' => TabSize
        }).sum
    }

    private def isWhiteChar(ch: Char) = ch == ' ' || ch == '\t'
}
```

Execution for this text gives:

```
val text =
    """
      |line1
      |line2
      |    line3
      |    line4
      |    line5
      |        line6
      |        line7
      |  line8
      |  line9
      |line10
      |   line11
      |   line12
      |   line13
    """.stripMargin
println(Preprocessor.preProcess(text))
```

... the following result

```
{
line1
line2
{
    line3
    line4
    line5
{
        line6
        line7
}
}
{
  line8
  line9
}
line10
{
   line11
   line12
   line13
}
}
```

And afterwords you can use the combinator library to do the parsing in a simpler fashion.

Hope this helps