# Parsing an indentation based language using parsimmon library

Tags: javascript, parsing, parser-combinators

My question is inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466727/parsing-an-indentation-based-language-using-scala-parser-combinators), but for javascript, using the parsimmon parser-combinator library. I want to parse an indentation-sensitive language, like python or yaml.

I've managed to convert the scala example in that answer to javascript easily enough - the key is the `chain` function in parsimmon, which is equivalent to the `>>` operator in scala's parser combinators - they both take a parser and a function that returns a parser, and the result of the first parser is passed to the function to choose the next parser.

However, I can't quite wrap my head around how to make this recursive. The example is for a single block - I don't see how to create nested blocks, tracking de-dent levels as needed to parse something like python.

Comment: I know code samples are encouraged, but I've spent 6 hours on this so far and don't have code that's even partially working yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one way to do it. It's probably not the best, and it's definitely not intuitive (I'm not sure I understand why it works, and I *wrote* it :) but it seems to be pretty robust.

Basically it says: a `tree` is a `line` optionally followed by a `block`. A `block`, in turn, is an indented list of `tree`s.

`indent` is a function that takes the current indentation level, and returns a parser that expects a line indented more than that. The returned parser returns a stack of previous indentation levels.

I said before it's robust - in fact, it's *too* robust. It accepts input that really ought to throw an error instead: if you un-indent to an indentation level that doesn't match a previous level, it basically "rounds up" to the next indentation level. I'm not sure where the logic to fix that should go - mutual recursion mixed with parser "chain"-ing is hard to follow!

```js
var {regex, seq} = Parsimmon;

function tree(state) {
    return seq(
        line,
        block(state).atMost(1).map(x => x[0]? x[0] : [])
    );
}

function block(state) { 
    return indent(state)
        .chain(tree).atLeast(1);
}

function indent(state) {
    return regex(/\s/).atLeast(state + 1)
        .map(x => x.length)
        .desc('indent');
}

let item = regex(/[^\s].*/).desc('item');
let line = item.skip(regex(/\n?/));
let start = block(-1);

let result = start.parse('top item 1\n  sub item 1\n  sub item 2\n' + 
    '    even deeper\n  sub item 3\ntop item 2');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result['value'], null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jneen/parsimmon/master/src/parsimmon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of Parsimmon. I realize this question is really old, but I stumbled across it and wanted to answer.

The `python-ish.js` example in the parsimmon repo on GitHub should help you understand how to parse an indentation-based language.

It's very similar to Josh's answer, but I think a little easier to understand.

https://github.com/jneen/parsimmon/blob/master/examples/python-ish.js

```js
"use strict";

// Run me with Node to see my output!

let util = require("util");
let P = require("..");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Because parsing indentation-sensitive languages such as Python requires
// tracking state, all of our parsers are created inside a function that takes
// the current parsing state. In this case it's just the current indentation
// level, but a real Python parser would also *at least* need to keep track of
// whether the current parsing is inside of () or [] or {} so that you can know
// to ignore all whitespace, instead of further tracking indentation.
//
// Implementing all of Python's various whitespace requirements, including
// comments and line continuations (backslash at the end of the line) is left as
// an exercise for the reader. I've tried and frankly it's pretty tricky.
function PyX(indent) {
  return P.createLanguage({
    // This is where the magic happens. Basically we need to parse a deeper
    // indentation level on the first statement of the block and keep track of
    // new indentation level. Then we make a whole new set of parsers that use
    // that new indentation level for all their parsing. Each line past the
    // first is required to be indented to the same level as that new deeper
    // indentation level.
    Block: r =>
      P.seqObj(
        P.string("block:"),
        r.NL,
        ["n", r.IndentMore],
        ["first", r.Statement]
      ).chain(args => {
        const { n, first } = args;
        return PyX(n)
          .RestStatement.many()
          .map(rest => ["BLOCK", first, ...rest]);
      }),

    // This is just a statement in our language. To simplify, this is either a
    // block of code or just an identifier
    Statement: r => P.alt(r.Block, r.Ident),

    // This is a statement which is indented to the level of the current parse
    // state. It's called RestStatement because the first statement in a block
    // is indented more than the previous state, but the *rest* of the
    // statements match up with the new state.
    RestStatement: r => r.IndentSame.then(r.Statement),

    // Just a variable and then the end of the line.
    Ident: r => P.regexp(/[a-z]+/i).skip(r.End),

    // Consume zero or more spaces and then return the number consumed. For a
    // more Python-like language, this parser would also accept tabs and then
    // expand them to the correct number of spaces
    //
    // https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation
    CountSpaces: () => P.regexp(/[ ]*/).map(s => s.length),

    // Count the current indentation level and assert it's more than the current
    // parse state's desired indentation
    IndentSame: r =>
      r.CountSpaces.chain(n => {
        if (n === indent) {
          return P.of(n);
        }
        return P.fail(`${n} spaces`);
      }),

    // Count the current indentation level and assert it's equal to the current
    // parse state's desired indentation
    IndentMore: r =>
      r.CountSpaces.chain(n => {
        if (n > indent) {
          return P.of(n);
        }
        return P.fail(`more than ${n} spaces`);
      }),

    // Support all three standard text file line endings
    NL: () => P.alt(P.string("\r\n"), P.oneOf("\r\n")),

    // Lines should always end in a newline sequence, but many files are missing
    // the final newline
    End: r => P.alt(r.NL, P.eof)
  });
}

// Start parsing at zero indentation
let Pythonish = PyX(0);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let text = `\
block:
  alpha
  bravo
  block:
         charlie
         delta
         echo
         block:
          foxtrot
  golf
`;

function prettyPrint(x) {
  let opts = { depth: null, colors: "auto" };
  let s = util.inspect(x, opts);
  console.log(s);
}

let ast = Pythonish.Statement.tryParse(text);
prettyPrint(ast);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse nested blocks you basically have to **preprocess** the input script and insert some predefined special characters INDENT / DEDENT in places where indentation increases or decreases, only then parsing rules should be applied. These special characters are equivalent to braces { and } in traditional languages, so the preprocessing effectively converts your language from indentation-based to a braces-delimited one for internal purposes of the parsing process.

As an example of how this can be done, you can check [Hypertag](http://hypertag.io/), which is an indentation-based language implemented in Python. In particular, you may want to see the [preprocess()](https://github.com/mwojnars/hypertag/blob/9d877059994cfff15e681c72ad0c208b3c1bc59c/src/hypertag/core/ast.py#L195) method and the [grammar](https://github.com/mwojnars/hypertag/blob/main/src/hypertag/core/grammar.py) specification - the latter assumes that preprocessing has already been performed and all indentation was replaced with INDENT_* and DEDENT_* characters.

Answer (score 0):

Parsimmon isn't really built for parsing context-specific languages like ones with indentation delimiting.

I wrote [parsinator.js](https://github.com/fresheneesz/parsinator.js) for that exact reason. It has the ability to pass state, which allows you to pass around what the indentation state is.

Here's an example of a simple langauge where you specify the indentation the block will have to see how state works. But you could just as easily parse some whitespace and set the indentation state that way.

```
const parsers = lazyParsers({
  block: function() {
    return ser(indentDeclaration, indent, 'hello')
  },
  indent: function() {
    return times(this.get('indent'), ' ')
  },
  indentDeclaration: function() {
    return ser('indent=', number, ':\n').value(function(value) {
      this.set('indent', Number(value[1]))
      return value
    })
  },
  number: function() {
    return ser(/[0-9]/)
  },
})
eval(importParsers(parsers, 'parsers'))

const result = block().debug().parse(
  "indent=4:\n"+
  "   hello"
)
console.log(displayResult(result))
```